# I decreased the height of the AgGrid row, but how to decrease the height of the customer editor's background for the cell?

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid

I am building React app with AgGrid and my code for the grid with decreased row height is:

```
<div className="float-left ag-theme-alpine"
        style={{
          height: '500px',
          width: '100%',
          margin: '4px',
        }}
      >
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columns}
          rowData={getPosForView}
          rowSelection='single'
          rowHeight={28}
          //onRowDoubleClicked={onRowDoubleClicked}
          //onCellValueChanged={handleCellValueChanged}
        ></AgGridReact>
      </div>
```

The column definition contains indiction of the custom editor for the cell:

```
 { field: 'structure', headerName: 'Structure', width: 150, sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true, valueSetter: handleCellValueUpdate, cellEditor: SimpleTextEditor },
```

And the code for my custom editor ir:

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
class SimpleTextEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: props.value,
        };
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.state.value;
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    }

    //<div style={{ boxSizing: 'border-box', height: '100%' }}>

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ boxSizing: 'border-box', height: '28px', border: '1px solid blue', margin: '2px' }}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    style={{ height: '28px', width: '100%', border: 'none', padding: '0', margin: '0' }}
                    //style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', border: 'none', padding: '0' }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SimpleTextEditor;
```

Now the editor shows Input in the right height (equal to the required row height), but the edit contains background whose wight is exactly the height of the original height of the row, i.e. there is white background with empty space at the bottom. How can I control, reduce this backgroung?

I checked the style for this element and it is:

```
div.ag-cell.ag-cell-normal-height.ag-cell-value.ag-cell-focus.ag-cell-inline-editing
```

Most likely I should set custom value for this style-class manually? I am not sure how to do this and I am not sure isn't it too dirty? I would prefer setting style in the grid instance or in the cell editor component.

**Information added**: I have definition in custom css file which one view jsx of my React app loads:

```
.ag-row {
    --ag-row-height: 60px;
}
```

And the presence of this instruction determines the appearance of extra background space/height in the cell editor in my original view jsx, so, css from another view spills into my original view. Now I am eagerly reading about scoping of css for my React app.